# Flask modifying Session variable with APScheduler

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I have trouble setting up a Apscheduler which interacts with the session variable. I always get the error `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.`

The idea of the following code is having a play button, that when pressed triggers a job which increases the week counter by one every 3 seconds.

parts of my current code:

**init**.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.start()
app.config.from_object(Config)
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/play_btn', methods=['GET'])
def play_btn():
    print("play")
    scheduler.add_job(func=increment_week, trigger="interval", seconds=3, id="play_btn")
    return "nothing"

def increment_week():
    #with app.app_context():
    #    print(session(app))
    session['week'] += 1
    # print("Only printing is working fine")
```

It makes sense that the `incement_week()` functions needs the app context to retrieve the session. Unfortunately, my attempts all failed except when just plain printing a static string (which of cause needs no context).

Comment: Actually you can modify the value of the session variable by defining the increment_week function within the play_btn function (and adding a @copy_current_request_context decorator). But for some reason when accessing this session variable from outside it is not changed